# Big Sur Bootcamp stuck partitioning

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, partition, big-sur

I have a 2016 MBP with Big Sur and 170GB of internal drive space free and when trying to use Bootcamp to partition the drive with an 80GB disc for Windows 10 and it is stuck in the partitioning phase at ~40%...

[image]

What can I do to complete the process?

Attempting to quit the app complains that the process hasn’t been completed so it can’t quit. My only choice has been to close the MBP until later.

Here is the output of `diskutil list`:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         500.0 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     313.4 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 292.7 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                611.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      6.4 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.1 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.1 GB    disk1s5s1

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-GB... +5.4 GB     disk2
```

After what amounts to 2.5hrs (the MBP was closed for about a day, but went to sleep and awoke just fine) I see "Your disk could not be partitioned":

[image]

I then ran the `First Aid` in `Disk Utility` which claimed to be successful:

[image]

However, upon running `Bootcamp` and going through the disk partitioning again, I had the same result as first seen above ("Your disk could not be partitioned.")

Comment: The next step probably depends on how recent your backup is. If it's from today you can afford to just wipe it all & start over.

Comment: How long has it been stuck for

Comment: I don’t have the guts to wipe it and start over. It’s been stuck for 2 hrs.

Comment: The partitioning phase can take a long time. However, 2 hours does seem exceptional long. I am not sure the percents mean, but I am sure 40% does not mean 40% of the total time needed to complete the partitioning.

Comment: You're right - it means 40% of the overall progress bar. I've posted a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the response of the terminal command :

```
diskutil list
```

To see if there is something done by BootCamp

Edit :

All is good in your diskutil.
Thirst, it's better have a save Time Machine before doing the nexts steeps.

You can try 2 things :

1. List snapshots on your system :

   tmutil listlocalsnapshots /

and il you see "old" snapshots you can suppress them and retry BootCamp

```
tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 9999999999999 4
```

2. If no change, you can boot in Recovery Mode (cmd+r at boot time) and do a "First Aid" (as advised in the error window) on the System Container of the internal SSD. And then retry BootCamp after normal reboot.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer. the requested information should be aded to the original question. The downside is that to get to this info, the OP will have to abandon any hope of the original procedure completing uninterrupted, so again it's down to how long since the last backup.

Comment: I have added the requested information to the post.